# Ruby check if variable has length

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Ok, this might sound like a silly question, but I'm having all sorts of problems with it and I'm sure there has to be an *easy* way to do this:

How do you check in ruby if a variable has length?

If I use `@dvds.length?` I get an error `undefined method length for ...` when it doesn't have a length.

Basically I've got some searches that mostly retrieve an ActiveRecord:Relation, but one or two simply return one entry since they search by id. I have things like:

```
@total = @dvds.length
```

To show how many we've found.

When @dvds does not contain any length, I get an error for undefined method. I did something like:

```
if @dvds.class == 'ActiveRecord:Relation'
```

to get around one error, but this is horrible and prone to more errors.

There has got to be a Ruby way of checking whether a variable has length or not that is a lot prettier and easier no?

Ideally I'm looking for something like:

```
@total = @dvds.length if @dvds.length
```

Or similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask; why does `@dvds` sometimes have no `length`? It seems like a variable named `dvds` should either be an array, or an ActiveRecord scope (which behaves like an array).

Comment: @MatthewRudy, copied from the question above: *but one or two simply return one entry since they search by id* :) To avoid this issue, I've since changed them to instead use `.where` which will return an array. But Alex's response is a great help.

Comment: I would choose to change the searches so that they all return collections, or at least wrap the calls so that you know @dvds is always plural.    `@dvds = [Dvd.find_by_id(1)]`

Comment: @DGM, Ah, this one is very smart, I hadn't even thought of that, thanks.

Comment: If this is a list of DVDs I'd suggest always using the same object (I'd suggest a relation). Then you can chain in ordering, pagination, and extra filters, without breaking anything. Doing a `where(:id => 234)` is actually the best solution sometimes.

Comment: @MatthewRudy, I see what you mean, good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check whether an object responds to specified method using [Object#respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) method:

```
obj.respond_to? :length # true or false
```